# В или во? Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: **во** Млечном пути или **в** Млечном пути?
Мне всегда казалось, что первый вариант правильнее для более быстрого произношения; когда произносится "в Млечном пути", приходится "спотыкаться" о букву М после В.

Answer (score 2):

О случаях добавления гласного **о** к предлогу **в** можно посмотреть в [**словаре управления**](https://upravlenie.academic.ru/118/%D0%B2_%E2%80%94_%D0%B2%D0%BE).

Там же сказано, что в отдельных случаях возможно параллельное употребление этих предлогов, например:
в введении — во введении, в сто крат — во сто крат.

Мне кажется, что мы имеем дело как раз с таким случаем.
Можно провести аналогию с использованием предлогов **в — во** со словом "младенчество" (в младенчестве — чаще):

*Представьте, что погиб **в младенчестве** Ньютон,

И пресловутый плод зря совершил паденье,

Неужто не открыт бы был закон,

Что объяснил земное притяженье?*
А. Татьмянин

*Нас было девять человек детей. Все мои братья и сестры умерли **во младенчестве.***
А. С. Пушкин. Капитанская дочка

В одной и той же [**статье**](http://www.astronews.ru/cgi-bin/mng.cgi?page=news&news=6045) употреблены оба варианта:

**В** Млечном Пути может быть около 100 миллионов планет, подходящих для жизни.
Исходя из того, что **во** Млечном Пути находится более 10 миллиардов звезд, эти расчеты говорят о том, что...

Думаю, что окончательный выбор предлога зависит от контекста и, собственно, от авторского восприятия. Но стоит отметить, что в словосочетании предлог "в" используется гораздо чаще.

Comment: Частотность (согласно Нацкорпусу) 36:3.

Comment: Благодарю за справку. Она некоторым образом подтверждает мой ответ.